# LINQ query with different join cases

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I am trying to pull data from 2 tables.  One of the tables is a view that pulls information from even more tables and puts it into a more usable piece of information.

Basically I want to query the first table where a specific item number occurs, and for each record that is found, then I want to look at 3 different columns in that record and pull a value from one of the three (if it is a vehicle, its the VIN column, if it is an employee its the EMP_ID column, etc) and then look it up in my view and pull the value in a different column.

**UPDATE**

```
var returnQuery = from t1 in db.TRANSACTION_TRACKINGs
                              where t1.ITEM_NUM == Convert.ToInt32(itemNo)
                              from t2 in db.VIEW_CWTS_EMP_VEH_UNIT_LOOKUPs
                              where Convert.ToString(t1.NEW_EMP_ID) == t2.IDENTIFIER || t1.UNIT_ID == t2.IDENTIFIER || t1.VIN == t2.IDENTIFIER
                              select new { QTY = t1.QTY, DESC = t2.DESCRIPTION, TYPE = t2.TYPE };
```

This query gives me results!  But some of the results are listed twice in my gridview.  Not sure whats happening there.

Comment: Have you tried Linqpad and taken a look at the SQL generated?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot install Linqpad on my work computer.

Comment: What are the "ton of errors"? Both of your attempts seem reasonable. Does `var returnQuery = from t1 in db.TRANSACTION_TRACKINGs where t1.ITEM_NUM == Convert.ToInt32(itemNo) select t1` return any results?

Comment: I think that the problem was the EMP_ID should have been NEW_EMP_ID and I was getting no results.  I changed my LINQ query and I got results but some of them are listed twice.